# javascript not running/debugging on vs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to run and debug a javascipt file. I followed the guide on the official website and downloaded Node JS (v16.14.0) and the javascript debugger extension.
I made this in both my laptop and the Desktop, however on the laptop I cannot make it work.
When I press F5 to debug the file it just doesn't do anything (really), no error or anything is shown on the output or Debug console. I also tryied to create a launch.json as following:

```
{      
"version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "type": "pwa-node",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Launch Program",
          "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
          ],
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\RicertaBT.js"
        }
      ]
    }
```

and still same story, no life sign.
At this point I am actually confused and have no idea on what to do.
I should also mention that the code I am trying to run is 100% working with 0 errors (I excecuted it on Node JS terminal).

Comment: Try just running `node RicertaBT.js`, does it have any errors?

Comment: It runs with no errors but doesn't show anything

Comment: Nvm, I was miswriting the file name, on the terminal with `node RicercaBT.js` (I changed the file name) it runs with no issues